# How can we setup openvpn with shorewall on ubuntu server?

Tags: dhcp, openvpn

I have one ubuntu machine in which I installed dhcp and shorewall.
Now I have setup openvpn in this machine.
outside clients are able to connect vpn and they can browse also.

Problem:-- client are not able to ping local servers in the network by name (by ip they can ping), So problem is that I am not able to use my local DNS over openvpn.

So anyone can please suggest how to use local DNS over openvpn instead of google DNS.
...
Thanks in advance